# Evaluating Limit

Tags: limits

I am trying to evaluate the following limit :

$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\ln{e(1+\frac{1}{x})^{1-x}}$

I could reduce it to the following form :

$\lim_{x\to\infty} x+x(1-x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$

But what should I do next? Is this reduction wrong?

Comment: Looks wrong, $(1-x)^{1/x}$ does not even make sense for $x$ large and arbitrary.

Comment: I used the fact that a limit of the form $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)}$ which tends to $1^{\infty}$ can be wriiten as $\lim_{x\to a} e^{g(x)[f(x)-1]}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reduction cannot be correct, since for example $(1-x)^{1/x}$ does not even exist (in the reals) for $x=1000$.

I suggest "simplifying" the logarithm. We get that our expression is equal to
$$x\left(1+(1-x)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right).$$
Now expand $\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$ using the beginning of the Maclaurin expansion of $\ln(1+t)$.